# how to forward ports through multiple hops with iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, linux-networking, port-forwarding

I've been wrestling with this for some time now and despite my efforts and can't make it work.
I want to forward ports from the public IP to a host (host1) on the corporate network. Thing is, there are multiple "hops" in between. The host is behind a firewall which is behind a linux router set as a vpn client. All traffic from the corporate network then goes through the vpn to a VPS in the cloud set as the vpn server and then to the internet (I hope I'm clear enough...)
Here's a rough schematic :

NC1 <==> Internet <==> VPS (VPN server) <==> Linux router (VPN client) <==> Firewall <==> Network (host1 with netcast listener on port 9000)

Now here are the iptables rules I've set in the VPS :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens3 -o tun0 -p tcp --syn --dport 9000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i ens3 -o tun0 -d 10.8.0.7 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o ens3 -s 10.8.0.7 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens3 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.7

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -p tcp --dport 9000 -d 10.8.0.7 -j SNAT --to-source <Public IP>

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o tun0 --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
```

With those rules I managed to establish a connection from the internet to the linux router no problem

Now I'm trying to forward those same ports from the linux router to the client host (the appropriate redirection rules are already set in the firewall) :

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp0s8 -p tcp --syn --dport 9000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o enp0s8 -d 10.0.2.11 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o tun0 -s 10.0.2.11 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -p tcp --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.11

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 9000 -d 10.0.2.11 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.2.100

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o enp0s8 --dport 9000 -j MASQUERADE
```

10.0.2.11 is the WAN IP of the firewall and 10.0.2.100 the IP of the enp0s8 interface of the linux router connected to the firewall. 10.8.0.7 is the tun0 IP of the linux router.

This is where things stop working. When I set up a netcat listener on host1 and try to connect from the internet (NC1) I get a connection timed out error.

Here is a tcpdump output from the NC1 computer trying to connect to the netcat listener on host1 :

```
13:57:05.541009 IP NC1.59820 > xx.xx.xx.xx.9000: Flags [S], seq 681754542, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2294604797 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

tcpdump from the tun0 interface of the linux router :

```
15:53:18.060563 IP 10.8.0.1.59818 > 10.8.0.7.9000: Flags [S], seq 3131331659, win 29200, options [mss 1308,sackOK,TS val 2294404076 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

tcpdump from the enp0s8 interface of the linux router :

```
15:53:18.060619 IP 10.0.2.100.59818 > 10.0.2.11.9000: Flags [S], seq 3131331659, win 29200, options [mss 1308,sackOK,TS val 2294404076 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I should also mention that with the linux router directly connected to the internet (and of course replacing the interfaces an IPs in the iptables rules) the connection establishes just fine.

This is probably something stupid but right now I don't see it.

Comment: removed my answer. actually it's not very clear what and where is the client. you should edit the question and add an example (in the question). you should also do captures with tcpdump on the router and see what is replying no route to host (which side? no idea, I'm not even sure where is the client, or if the client is really a client or a server)

Comment: Post edited for (hopefully) more clarity

Comment: Now you should do captures with tcpdump to see what system is really answering. Since there's NAT, seing an IP can't always tell what sent it. For example what is seen on each interface of the router (to be captured with separate tcpdumps, one per interface, not using "any")

Comment: Here I added the tcpdump outputs from the 2 interfaces of the Linux router and an updated one from NC1. Each were repeated something like 6 times with absolutely no difference so I only pasted one

Answer (score 0):

OK so it finally works.
Turns out it was some kind of bug in the firewall. After I installed an update which required a reboot I gave it another try and it worked no problem. Maybe an old iptables rule in the firewall was the blocker...